# How do you ignore trailing slash in webflux in spring boot 3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

In Spring Boot 3, they have changed so that trailing slashes, by default, are no longer ignored. For example, if I have a GET resource, `/users`, and I navigate to `/users/` then Spring Boot webflux will now respond with 404.

You can change this by implementing a `WebFluxConfigurer` and overriding the `configurePathMatching` method:

```java
@Override
public void configurePathMatching(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
     configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch();
}
```

However, `setUseTrailingSlashMatch` is deprecated, and the docs says to use `PathPatternParser.setMatchOptionalTrailingSeparator(boolean)` instead. However, I don't understand how/where you actually configure this.

So the question is, how do I set `PathPatternParser.setMatchOptionalTrailingSeparator(boolean)`?

Comment: I'm not sure of the answer to this, but for what it's worth, [`PathPatternParser.setMatchOptionalTrailingSeparator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/util/pattern/PathPatternParser.html#setMatchOptionalTrailingSeparator(boolean)) also seems to be deprecated now, with a message saying '*transparent support for trailing slashes is deprecated as of 6.0 in favor of configuring explicit redirects through a proxy, Servlet/web filter, or a controller*'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @joe-clay has mentioned in his comment, `PathPatternParser.setMatchOptionalTrailingSeparator(boolean)` is deprecated as well in favour of explicit redirects. So you have 3 options:

1. Declare both routes explicitly in the controller handler `@GetMapping({"/users", "/users/"})`. The downside is that you need to do this for every controller, but can be used as a stop-gap solution.
2. Implement `org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter` interface to explicitly redirect to the desired url. Something along these lines:

```java
@Override
public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {

    URI originalUri = exchange.getRequest().getURI();

    if (/* check condition for trailing slash using originalUri getPath(), getQuery() etc. */) {
        String originalPath = originalUri.getPath();
        String newPath = originalPath.substring(0, originalPath.length() - 1); // ignore trailing slash
        try {
            URI newUri = new URI(originalUri.getScheme(),
                    originalUri.getUserInfo(),
                    originalUri.getHost(),
                    originalUri.getPort(),
                    newPath,
                    originalUri.getQuery(),
                    originalUri.getFragment());

            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.MOVED_PERMANENTLY);    // optional
            response.getHeaders().setLocation(mutatedUri);

            return Mono.empty();

        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
    return chain.filter(exchange);
}
```

3. Explicitly rewrite the incoming url in the proxy (for example using `rewrite` rules in nginx) to match the expected url.

In options 2 and 3, you may choose to return an `HTTP 301` response as well.

Comment: You don't happen to know the rationale for removing this option? I can understand that it's not default anymore, but given that it seems to be this difficult to re-enable it again, they must have really disliked it :)

Comment: There's a discussion on github which you can refer, esp this comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/28552#issuecomment-1152391820

Comment: Is there any cleaner or better-looking way nowadays, a few versions later?

Comment: Thank you for the options, but wow.. how verbose it is, very weird update from the Spring ream